# Convert moment.js object to JSON format

Tags: momentjs

Maybe this has been asked before, but I could not found it 
I want to convert the moment.js object to date of the following format

`/Date(1245398693390)/`

All what I found were doing the opposite, converting the previous format to moment js

Comment: Do you need a string like `/Date(1245398693390)/` from a moment object?

Comment: @VincenzoC yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`valueOf()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/). Here a live sample:

```js
console.log('/Date(' + moment().valueOf() + ')/');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```